# Setting MySQL column names

Tags: sql, mysql

Say I have these tables:

`people(id, name),`
`cars(person_id, car)`

and this query:

```
SELECT c.car
FROM people as p, cars as c
WHERE c.person_id = p.id
  AND p.id = 3
```

I want the `c.car` column to take its name from the `name` field in the `people` table, like this (invalid SQL, just to illustrate):

`SELECT c.car AS(SELECT name FROM people WHERE id = 3)`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias must be hardcoded in your query.  You can't change an alias based on data values.

You'll have to query both the car and the person's name (as shown by @VoteyDisciple's answer) and match them up in your application code after you've fetched them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand completely. The `c.car` field refers quite specifically to the `car` field in the `cars` table.

To refer to the `name` field in the `people` table, use `p.name`

```
SELECT c.car, p.name
FROM people as p, cars as c
WHERE c.person_id = p.id
  AND p.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't in general. What would be the column name if it returned multiple different results? If you know it can only return 1 result you would need to look that up then use dynamic SQL to alias the column in a separate query.